# Conditional expectation inequality

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expectation

Let $F_1\subset F_2$ and $\mathbb{E}X^2 < \infty$, then

$\mathbb{E}|X-\mathbb{E}(X|F_2)|^2 \le \mathbb{E}|X-\mathbb{E}(X|F_1)|^2 $

Can anyone help me with this proof? I know basic properties of conditional expectation but can't see how to use them here. Thank you.

My attempt:

$Y:=X-\mathbb{E}(X|F_1)$

Then I will need to show that:

$\mathbb{E}(|Y-\mathbb{E}(Y|F_2)|^2|F_2) \le \mathbb{E}(Y^2|F_2)$

But i don't see how can I move from here. I tried to employ Jensen Inequality but it gave me nothing. Any clue?

Comment: I have tried to solve this problem. But I can't. Why did you wanna show that the inequality hold? Which theorems are related to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Please

1 finish it

2 convince yourself if exchange the role of $F_1$ and $F_2$, the argument, mainly the bit at the bottom, does not work (not equal to 0).

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'll look at it when I get home.

Comment: I would be grateful if you checked my solution. Thank you again for your effort. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First:

$\mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X|F_2]|F_2]=\mathbb{E}[X|F_2]-\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|F_2]|F_2]=\mathbb{E}[X|F_2]-\mathbb{E}[X|F_2]=0$

So I have.

$\mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X|F_1]]^2=\mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X|F_2]]^2+\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|F_2]-\mathbb{E}[X|F_1]]^2\ge \mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X|F_2]]^2$

Where the middle equality holds by the last bit of my answer, which tells us the cross term is 0

Is that correct? Thank you again!

Comment: Huh. Where did you use jensen's inequality?, you just drop the 2nd term of the middle part, because it is positive.

Comment: I will edit the correct answer, you can check against previous version.

Comment: Yes, it's obviously simpler! Thanks, I was blind. But using Jensen inequality to the second term also would lead to the same. Since $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}[X|F_1])=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}[X|F_2])=\mathbb{E}X$ And there will be zero after we use Jensen inequality: $\mathbb{E}Z^2 \ge (\mathbb{E}Z)^2 $   I'm just curious if I missed something. Thanks.